# Java - keeping track of object types

Tags: java, oop

Let's say that I have abstract class Car and there are x concrete classes (RedCar, BlueCar ...) that extend class Car. Then I have class Garage that has property Car[] cars.

I want to write a boolean method to class Garage that will loop through the cars and returns true if searched car (one of concrete type (RedCar, BlueCar..) passed as parameter) was found, otherwise returns false.

What is the best way to do it?

For now, I have something like this :

```
public boolean hasCar(Class<? extends Car> c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
        if (c.isInstance(this.cars[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but wouldn't it be better if I create an enum with all possible Car types (subclasses of Car), add a property to class Car, which will hold the constant from enum and compare it based on it?

Something like this:

```
public enum CarType{
    RED_CAR, BLUE_CAR
}

public abstract class Car{
    public CarType type;
    Car(CarType type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class RedCar extends Car{
    public RedCar(){
        super(CarType.RED_CAR);
    }
}

public class BlueCar extends Car{
    public BlueCar(){
        super(CarType.BLUE_CAR);
    }
}

public class Garage{
    private Car[] cars;
    public boolean hasCar(CarType type) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
            if(this.cars[i].type == type){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which one is the better method?

Comment: both methods will work the same in my opinion

Comment: yes, they will, but I just want to know which way is more profesional and how would this handle experienced programmers

Comment: You should store them in different collections if you want to check/search based on class type.

Comment: But in that case I would have to make changes to base class (adding new collections) when I want to implement new types (subclasses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the subclasses don't add any state to the base class and don't change or add behavior by adding or overriding methods to/of the base class, then you shouldn't have subclasses. Just having a Car class with a `type` attribute is sufficient.

If the subclasses have a good reason to exist, then you could indeed use an enum, but that would prevent adding any other type of car (without also changing the enum).

Having a method which searches for a specific type of car looks like a design smell to me. That probably means that the Car class is not sufficiently polymorphic: instanceof and casts are not very OO.

Comment: Well this is just a very simplified example. In my real project the subclasses are more robust, they change state of base class and override methods. The real problem isn't even about cars (it's about sensors and concrete types of sensors), I should have mentioned that. Anyway, I don't like the first one (with instanceof) solution either, that's why I am asking for better one. So my second one solution, assuming that all subclasses have reason to exist, is fine and OO friendly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're definitely sticking with having the different colours of car as subtypes, I would say your first version is better - your second will involve updating the enumeration every time you add a new type of car and involves a lot of copy-and-paste style coding for the constructors.

However, I'd recommend that if you want to search the garage for certain colours of car it would make sense to have the colour as a property of the car rather than having to check the car's type. In your second example, the code looks 'cleaner' as you're not using reflection, but you've basically got duplicated information as a car's colour is represented both by its type and by its CarType property. Simply having a single Car type with a Colour value would make this code a lot shorter and neater. Though with this said, I don't know what you ultimately want to do with this so your approach of having subtypes may still be best - take what I say with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Well this is just a very simplified example. In my real project the subclasses are more robust, they change state of base class and override methods, so I can't replace them by one property. The problem I am dealing with is wether I should use refleciton or add a type property and compare it base on it. And I don't mind a lot of copy-and-paste, I just want to have clean, nice and OO code

Answer (score 1):

The enum solution you posted will only work if you want to confirm that a car of a certain *type* is found. Not the specific car object itself. Also, if your Car subclasses don't have any difference other than a type variable, you probably don't need subclasses.

The first method looks fine, and may be shortened (a little) like this:

```
public boolean hasCar(Class<? extends Car> c) {
    for (Car car : this.cars) {
        if (c.isInstance(car) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Car subclasses have differences, they have to be declared in own class. But thanks, I didn't know about looping arrays like this

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could use is passing a filter object and asking the car itself if it matches the filter. the implemntation details of the filter may depend on your real life example (and may even compare by using **instanceof()**), but in the simplified example you give, it may be a string or an enum specifying the color you are looking for. something like

```
public class CarFilter()
{
String Color;
}
```

In the base class of car you have a method:

```
public boolean matchesFilter(CarFilter filter){} //maybe abstract?
```

In the derived class RedCar the method maybe implemnted like this:

```
public boolean matchesFilter(CarFilter filter)
{
 return filter.Color == "red"; //MAYBE case insensitive?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, I have to ask my self which offers the easiest extensibility? I would say the first implementation.